# Permission denied when installing Bazel 0.16.1 on macos 10.13.6

Tags: macos, installation, bazel

I'm attempting to install Bazel on Macos using the Bazel installer. A permission denied error occurs inside the `/var/temp` directory during the installation.

```
$ ./bazel-0.16.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user
Uncompressing......Extracting Bazel installation...
FATAL: failed to open '/var/tmp/_bazel_clavius/install/2fc3f6f2633d78815ad4e94b45964b0e.tmp.21064/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar' for syncing: (error: 13): Permission denied
```

If I check, I do have read and execute permissions on the file.

```
$ ls -la /var/tmp/_bazel_clavius/install/2fc3f6f2633d78815ad4e94b45964b0e.tmp.21064/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 clavius  wheel  44149867  8 Sep  2028 /var/tmp/_bazel_clavius/install/2fc3f6f2633d78815ad4e94b45964b0e.tmp.21064/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you successfully installed Bazel and the error comes not from the installer but from Bazel itself, as it tried extracting the so-called "embedded tools". This is possibly a bug -- if you would be so kind to [file a Bazel bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new)[1], that'd be great!

Let's investigate:

- If you retry the installation, does it succeed?
- If you install like `$ ./bazel-0.16.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --prefix=$HOME/foo`, can you run `$HOME/foo/bin/bazel` successfully?
- Could it be that you already have a `/var/tmp/_bazel_clavius/install/2fc3f6f2633d78815ad4e94b45964b0e` directory? If so, what's the output of `ls -la /var/tmp/_bazel_clavius/install/2fc3f6f2633d78815ad4e94b45964b0e/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar`?
- Did you run Bazel before trying to install the new version? I reckon it's possible that there's a bug in the installation directory computation logic and your new version tries overwriting the files of the old version, and the old version is still running.

---

[1] https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new